# How can I ask a question that, by its nature, will be "too broad"?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I'm specifically interested in looking for "gotcha" instances in upgrading Kubuntu 14.04.1 to 16.04, to help me decide whether to upgrade or ride 14.04 another two years.  I know there's a newer version of KDE involved, and there are significant changes to the underlying Ubuntu (one I just encountered in a [closed as too broad] question was the change from `upstart` to `systemd`).  The basic problem is, I've already deleted one question of this nature, on the brink of being closed as too broad, and I don't know enough about 16.04 to ask the individual, very specific questions that comments on that question seemed to suggest are the only "interesting" kind or ones that fit this format.

In other words, I don't know enough to learn more here, and I don't have hundreds of hours of free time to become familiar with 16.04 (install the beta in a separate partition, and play with it *a lot*, while rebooting to 14.04 when I need to get anything actually done).  How can I get the information to make an upgrade decision?

Comment: I think people think you're asking for an opinion.  I wouldn't ask that question at all.  My counter-question would be "Why wouldn't you at LEAST get on the latest LTS?  It will only get harder later."

Comment: "Comments aren't for discussion" usually follows this kind of reply, but...  I haven't got time to chase "this doesn't work" for weeks, any more than I have time to spend tens or hundreds of hours where I can't reliably get anything done, just learning whether 16.04 is going to do something terrible like break my Wine (which was what let me abandon Windows back in Vista days).  My computer is a tool, and I switched to Kubuntu because I got tired of the way Windows kept wanting me to learn a new interface every couple years, never mind invalidating everything I knew about "under the hood".

Comment: You can have somewhat open-ended discussions on [Ubuntu Discourse](https://discourse.ubuntu.com).

Comment: @muru: can you convert that to an answer???

Comment: [/r/ubuntu](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/) and [the ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org) are other good places you could ask this.

Comment: Although upgrades usually work, they can fail as well. The known bugs or problems are always in the release notes - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseNotes . Upgrades can always fail, so back up first. Debugging a failed upgrade usually takes longer then a fresh install, so some people simply fresh install, there are several strategies for restoring packages from a package list. Otherwise your question is too broad as you are asking us to predict problems outside the release notes.

Answer (score 6):

No, questions on Stack Exchange need to be ["practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face."](https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask) That question would fall out "actual problems that you face" part. The only way to know what "gotcha" would upgrading have to **you**, can only be accurately answered by **you**, when you upgrade. Others will only share **their** experiences about **their** upgrade process, which obviously may vary from what you could experience.

Upgrades are painless in general, and problems are found before you upgrade. As always you should keep backups of your important files in case anything (not only the upgrade) goes wrong.

Comment: So the response to "How can i do this" is "No"? What?

Comment: @StarOS yes....